# Python binary operators and word splitting

Tags: python

I've been working on some homework I've been given and I've ran into a couple problems. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on them and perhaps give me some examples to help aide me.

My **first** question deals with binary operators in python.

*Problem #13:  Python supports 18 different binary operators. Experiment with each of these, using arguments that are both integer, both floating point, and both string. Not all operators work with each argument type. Fill in the following table. For each operator, provide either a short description and indicate the type of the result or the words “not legal”.*

```
Operator        Integer             Floating point           String
  +
  -         
  *         
  **            
  /         
  %         
  <<            
  >>            
  &         
  |         
  ^         
  <         
  >         
 <=         
 >=         
 ==         
 !=         
 <>
```

In this example we're supposed to explain how to operator works as an integer, float point and a string. What confuses me is the float and string aspect, using the addition portion as an example:

Would the integer aspect be something like x=3 y=4 x+y=answer (to show as an integer)? If so how would I go about showing examples of the float and string portion.

My **second** question deals with string splitting

*Problem #20:  Each row in the following table consists of a starting word and an ending word. Assign the starting word to the name w. Then using only indexing and slicing commands, convert the starting word into the ending word.*

```
Starting word   Ending word    Command
w=’kyoto’       ‘tokyo’        w[3:]+w[:3]
w=’bread’       ‘bead’         w[0]+w[2:]
w=’kartasura’   ‘surakarta’    w[5:]+w[:5]
w=’listen’      ‘silent’
```

As you can see I've completed the first three which seemed relatively simple, I had to rearrange the words. The final one confuses me because I am not longer flipping the back with the front or vise versa. Instead I am rotating sections, now I am rotating lis to sil and ten to ent and I'm not exactly sure how to rotate letters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, TY.

Comment: You should clear these things with your instructor rather than trying to crowd-source an opinion from the internet. Your question isn't so much about how to solve a problem than it is about semantics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What confuses me is the float and string aspect, using the addition portion as an example?

```
3 + 4
3.5 + 4.25
'hello' + ' world'
```

> The final one confuses me because I am not longer flipping the back with the front or vise versa.

```
w[2::-1] + w[4:6] + w[3]
```

Comment: I was putting the minus in the wrong place then, no wonder it wouldn't work. I was trying to do something like W[2:]-[w:4] and kept getting errors, that explains why then. Thank You, I now know how to approach the remaining aspects.